# A quebra de mirror influencia na auditoria de servidor?

Tags: sql, sql-server

A quebra de mirror influencia na auditoria de servidor? Pergunto isso porque, nas bases de dados onde eu preciso refazer o mirroring por algum motivo, também tenho que especificar a auditoria novamente (BASE>>Security>>Database Audit Spec. >> Dois cliques na auditoria >> Campo Audit).